# How user can cancel order in spree?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree

I'm playing around with a "customer canceling the order in Spree". I am using Spree Pay-pal Express.. From User perspective, i am able to order a product. But being a user, how can i cancel the order.?? I am using Spree 2.4.1 version and rails 4.1.
 Can anyone tell how a customer can cancel the order in Spree.
Thanks!

Comment: Did you ask the developers?

Comment: Duplicate of [How to cancel order in spree?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27481193/how-to-cancel-order-in-spree) Please do not spam us...

Answer (score 0):

By default in Spree 2.4.1 a customer can not cancel an Order.